# Java task does nothing?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task, executorservice

I have a program in which I use multiple tasks controlled by an *ExecutorService*. I actually used *Runnable* and now changed it to tasks, however I seem to have done something wrong because everything that should happen inside my tasks is **not** happpening. I should mention, the program does not finish, it runs infinitly. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

```
public class Test{
    ExecutorService exec;

    public Test (){
        exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        run();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
    }

    private void run() {
        System.out.println("This works normal");
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call(){
                System.out.println("Here nothing happens already");
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    exec.submit(() -> { System.out.println("Offcourse no sub-task works either"); });
                return null;
            }
        };
        exec.submit(task);
    }
}
```

These are my imports:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
```

> I use:
>   - Netbeans IDE 8.2
>   - Java
>   - Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Now please explain why you are using that `Task`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an unusual feature, `Task` (which is part of the javafx package) implements both `Callable` and `Runnable`. When you submit your Task to the `ExecutorService` it calls the `Task.run` method, which has an empty, stubbed-out implementation in `Task`. If you override `run` in your anonymous class then you will see your code run.

Have you considered just creating an anonymous class directly out of `Callable`? Or are you intentionally using the `Task` class because you are working with JavaFX?

If you are working with JavaFX and are intentionally using `Task`, then the `Task` API suggests the following:

> Although ExecutorService defines several methods which take a
>   Runnable, you should generally limit yourself to using the execute
>   method inherited from Executor.

[Task API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

The `call` method is generally for when you are using a [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html)

To shut down an `ExecutorService`, you should invoke `exec.shutdown()`.